# Proof to a property of Euler's totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups, totient-function, multiplicative-function

The property is
$$\sum_{d|n}\phi(d) = n$$

And the proof provided is

> If $d$ divides $n$, let $C_d$ be the unique subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ of order $d$, and let $\Phi_d$ be the set of generators of $C_d$. Since all elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ generate one of the $C_d$, the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is the disjoint union of the $\Phi_d$ and we have
>   $$n = \text{Card}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) = \sum_{d|n}\text{Card}(\Phi_d) = \sum_{d|n}\phi(d)$$

But I can't prove to myself the uniqueness of the subgroups to let the rest fall together.

Comment: Well it certainly works for prime numbers: if $n$ is prime, then $\phi(n) = n - 1$ (all the numbers from $1 \leq k < n$).  But _both_ $n$ _and_ $1$ divide $n$ (when $n$ is prime) thus we get: $\phi(n) + \phi(1) = (n - 1) + 1 = n$.  I would start from there.  The next thing I would do is see what happens when you have $n = p_1p_2$ where $p_1, p_2$ is prime...then try to generalize from there.

Comment: Thanks Jared, but I'm not trying to find an alternative proof. I'm trying to understand a basic notion the proof I have is using.

Comment: The group is cyclic, so every subgroup is unique. Think about the least multiple of the generator in the subgroup (and this is the generator of the subgroup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you need to prove in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, there is a unique subgroup of order $d$ where $d|n$.  Suppose, $m\in\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, then $|m|$,the order of $m$, is $n/(n,m)$. So, if a subgroup $H$ has order $d$, then it is generated by $m$ where $n/(n,m)=d$.  Clearly $m=n/d$ is such a number. Any other such number must be a multiple of $n/d$, hence all possible generators of a group of order $d$ belong to the same subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it using induction on number prime divisor.

Suppose $\displaystyle k=p^r$ be a integer which has one prime divisor $p$

Then divisors of $k$ are $1, p,.......p^r$. So
$$\displaystyle\sum_{d|p^r}\phi(d)=\phi(1)+\phi(p)+.....\phi(p^r)=1+p-1+....p^r-p^{r-1}=p^r$$

Now suppose this is true for all those integers which have $s$ prime factors.

consider $Z=mq^t$ where m is an integer which have $s$ prime factor and q is a prime and $gcd(m,q)=1$

Then$$\displaystyle\sum_{d|\phi(Z)}\phi(Z)=\sum_{d|m}\Big(\phi(m)+\phi(mq)+\phi(mq^2)+......\phi(mq^t)\Big)=\sum_{d|m}\Big(\phi(m)+\phi(m)\phi(q)+\phi(m)\phi(q^2)+.....\phi(m)\phi(q^2)\Big)=\Big(\sum_{d|m}\phi(m)\Big)\Big(\phi(1)+\phi(q)+.....\phi(q^t)\Big)=mq^t=Z$$

And therefore $$Z=\sum_{d|\phi(Z)}\phi(Z)$$. So it completes the proof of result.